# What is this LEGO Star Wars Disney box with "5 items"?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Someone sent me this picture, asking me what this LEGO Star Wars box is.

[image]

It apparently doesn't have an item number, and it just says "5 items" ages 6+. What items might it contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a promotion for holders of the Black VIP Card, 
between the 17th and 19th of December LEGO allowed US and Canadian shoppers at their online and bricks and mortar stores the opportunity to add a free branded box containing five polybagged minifigs to their shopping cart if they spent $75 on LEGO Star Wars set

it contains

[Hoth Han Solo (5001621)](https://brickset.com/sets/5001621-1/Han-Solo)

[Stormtrooper Sergeant (5002938)](https://brickset.com/sets/5002938-1/Stormtrooper-Sergeant)

[Admiral Yularen (5002947)](https://brickset.com/sets/5002947-1/Admiral-Yularen)

[Scarif Stormtrooper (40176)](https://brickset.com/sets/40176-1/Scarif-Stormtrooper)

[DJ (40298)](https://brickset.com/sets/40298-1/DJ)

---

[Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5005704-1&name=Star%20Wars%20Box&category=[Star%20Wars][Promotional]#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

https://www.thebrickfan.com/lego-star-wars-box-5005704-promotion-live-on-shophome/

http://www.rebelscum.com/story/front/LEGO_5005704_Free_Star_Wars_Box_182741

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if 5005704 is on the box somewhere.